# SQL Query to get count of number of tags as 0 instead of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

My 3 tables have the following fields:

```
tags
----
id
name

photos
------
id
name
path
toDelete
star
flag

photo_tags
----------
photoId
tagId
```

and my query is currently:

```
SELECT tags.id, tags.name, tagsCount.tagsCount FROM tags LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT photo_tags.tagId, count(*) as tagsCount
    FROM `tags`
    INNER JOIN photo_tags ON tags.id = photo_tags.tagId
    GROUP BY photo_tags.tagId
) as tagsCount
ON tagsCount.tagId = tags.id
```

And I get back:

```
1 | Bob | NULL
2 | Bernie | 2 
3 | Harold | 1
4 | Jim | 5
```

Because bob doesn't appear in photo_tags, it is NULL. How can I make that 0 instead?

Also is a sub query the correct thing to use in this case?

Comment: For next time, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IFNULL()`. `IFNULL(check_exp, replace)` if the `check_exp` is `NULL` then it will be replace with `replace`

```
SELECT tags.id, tags.name, IFNULL(tagsCount.tagsCount,0) FROM tags LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT photo_tags.tagId, count(*) as tagsCount
    FROM `tags`
    INNER JOIN photo_tags ON tags.id = photo_tags.tagId
    GROUP BY photo_tags.tagId
) as tagsCount
ON tagsCount.tagId = tags.id
```

also your subquery seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `tagsCount.tagsCount` to `COALESCE (tagsCount.tagsCount, 0)`. The COALESCE statement selects the first non-null value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Additional note: COALESCE is an ANSI standard SQL; it works with the big four databases. At least in Oracle, it uses short-circuit evaluation, which is generally more efficient.